# powershell doesn't display or output boolean and increments values

Tags: php, laravel, powershell, tinker

I use virtual machine and homestead with virtualbox under windows 10.
When i run `php artisan tinker` and try to find user with `App\User::first()`,
it returns:

```
Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.1.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> App\User::first()
=> App\User {#70
     id:  ,        // no number here
     name: "free",
     email: "free@email.com",
     created_at: "1998-06-26 06:05:38",
     updated_at: "2018-02-09 15:31:47",
     is_admin:  ,  // no boolean here
   }
```

If I copy these code above and paste,it will display correctly like:

```
=> App\User {#70
     id: 1,
     name: "free",
     email: "free@email.com",
     created_at: "1998-06-26 06:05:38",
     updated_at: "2018-02-09 15:31:47",
     is_admin: 1,
   }
```

It works fine and display compeletly with git-bash,i think the problem is about the powershell. But I don't know how to fix it.I already google,but nothing like this been asked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emqLZ.png)

still can't fix it,google show nothing about it.weird... hope somebody known.

Comment: Isn't Psy Shell (PySh) a PHP shell? Regardless, none of what you posted is powershell.

Comment: I run `php artisan tinker` with powershell after `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh`